# Can't ping RPi from Win 10

Tags: raspbian, windows, ping

Pi is connected with cable, the router gave it IP 192.168.1.10 via DHCP. I can ping PI from router directly, from an Android phone (which is connected over WiFi), and from a friend's Win 7 laptop (over WiFi, not available atm). However, I cannot ping it from my Win 10 PC. SSH does not connect. I can, however, ping other computers in the network from the PC, as well as my router and my phone.

RPI is headless, so I cannot check it's settings without a network access, but again, it pings from anywhere except the Win10 PC.

Tried to turn off the firewall and the antivirus, to add rules to allow echo requests, both inbound and outbound.

Comment: Are you sure your windows and your RPI are on the same network ? Try to run `cmd` and `ipconfig` on your windows to check that the 3 first parts of the IP are the same.

Comment: yes I am: the window's IP is 192.168.1.2/24, besides it can ping the router (192.168.1.1) and other stuff on the network

Comment: Which specific tool are you using to ping, e.g. Cygwin, Windows bash prompt, other?

Comment: cmd on Win 10 (failes) and Win 7 laptop (pings), router's built in tool on router, and "ping" app on Android

Comment: If you are positive both devices are on the same physical network and ip subnet then the problem can only be a corrupt arp table or conflict which would normally be resolved by restarting...

Comment: Same issue for me... Did you find a solution ?